# Command button in Visualforce can't read selected item from dynamic drop down list

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I am looking for help from Visualforce (Salesforce) page guru.

Background: There is a drop down list (apex:selectList in terms of Visualforce page). Its select options are built by jQuery with returned data (in JSON format) from RemoteAction (in Controller).

Problem: it always reports error message (j_id0:j_id2:j_id3:j_id4:orgList: Validation Error: Value is not valid) when I click command button which sends selected item value to Controller.

Any thoughts? Thanks very much.

Troy

Visualforce markup:

```
<apex:panelGrid columns="2">
<apex:selectList id="orgList" value="{!selected}"  size="1">
</apex:selectList>
<apex:commandButton value="Add" action="{!add}" style="width:80px">
</apex:panelGrid>
```

JavaScript:

```
$j("input[id$='azc']").keyup(function(){
   var op = $j("select[id$=orgList]");
    if($j(this).val().length >= 6){
             op.empty().append('<option value=""></option>');
             OrgController.findOrgs($j(this).val(), function(result, event){
                  if(event.status){
                      var data =  $j.parseJSON('[' + result.replace(/'/g, '"') + ']');
                      $j.each(data, function(){
                          $j('<option />', {value: this['value'], text: this['label']}).appendTo(op);
                      }); 
                  }else{
                      alert(event.message);             
                  } 
              },{escape:true});
        }
```

OrgController

```
public String selected { get; set; }
public PageReference add(){
    Customer__c customer =  findSelected(selected);
    if(customer != null){
      customer.Pending__c = 'Yes';
      update customer; 
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: It would be extremely helpful if you could post the Visualforce/jQuery markup that you're using here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to use a normal (html) select list and send selected value to controller per hidden field like this (works for me):

```salesforce
<!-- If the user selects an option - we will fill out the hidden field with that value -->
<select size="1" id="orgList" onChange="jQuery('[id$=hiddenField]').val(document.getElementById(this.id).value);">
    <option value="none">--Please select--</option>
</select>

<!-- Now add new options -->
<script>
    var myOptions = {
        val2 : 'Val 2',
        val3 : 'Val 3'
    };

    var mySelect = jQuery('#orgList');

    jQuery.each(myOptions, function(val, text) {
        mySelect.append( jQuery('<option></option>').val(val).html(text) );
    });

</script>

<!-- Here is the hidden field assigned to the apex variable -->
<apex:inputHidden value="{!myselected}" id="hiddenField"/>

<apex:commandButton reRender="none" value="Get value"/>
```

Comment: Select options are built by jQuery without any issue. I didn't have much knowledge about Salesforce (just touched it couple of months ago) but looks like select options are not detected by controller (as options are appended in client side). Thanks

Comment: I have updated my solution because the first one dint not work :( But this one works good.

Comment: Hidden field is the key. Sweet. It works like a charm! Thanks very much for your help.