# Selected value in dropdown won't clear jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, salesforce, visualforce

I've attached a vertical screen shot of some crazy stuff going on. Am I right to expect `j$('[id$=Model_List]').children().remove();` to remove all items in a select list? For some reason the list is still holding on to the old selected value while clearing out the rest of the items.

I'm using the `<Apex:selectlist` in the html block, just not in the jQuery.

VG930M should be V243H as seen in hte console log...

Hopefully the screenshot gives you a better idea of what I'm talking about...

[image]

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Apparently it does not like removing the selected element. Did you try setting changing the value to empty first? General note: Including your HTML code, script and a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo is most of the time more useful than a screenshot.

Comment: I would but I'm pulling from a controller and it really wouldn't be the same code at that point? I'll keep it in mind next time...here's what I'm referring to.
http://jsfiddle.net/Sv3yd/

Comment: I think i've got what you want. You want to change (reload) the second picklist depending on selected value of the first picklist, right?

Comment: Right. I would however like the selected value to revert back to "Select a Model" or clear it out or something. As of right now it it's just sticking.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove all values from the drop down and reset the selected value.

```
j$("select[id$=Model_List] > option").remove();
j$("select[id$=Model_List]").val('');
```

Comment: And see, I tried that previously but no dice...this was the closest I could come to the way you're "supposed" to do it...or at least I think it is.

Comment: I just noticed that you are repopulating the select list after removing the elements you you try selecting the first value.
j$("select[id$=Model_List]").val(0);

Comment: Where should that go? I've added it after the initial value of "Select a mode" is set assuming that would set the initial value to selected.
            

j$('[id$=Model_List]').append('<option selected="selected" value="01">Select a Model</option>');
            j$("select[id$=Model_List]").val(0);

Comment: after the for loop, on line 69.

Comment: Still no luck :\ It's really odd because it shows the "Select a Model" in the dropdown, it just doesn't select it initially even though it has selected="selected". It has to be something related to visualforce/salesforce.

Comment: try updating the text value also,  j$("select[id$=Model_List]").text('');

Answer (score 0):

You also need to clear the selected value:

```
$('[id$=Model_List]').val('');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, that salesforce selectList can not be filled out or cleared with jQuery (sure, you can do it but controller will not take the value).

Try to make it like in this example, with a hidden field:

[Command button in Visualforce can't read selected item from dynamic drop down list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11989585/command-button-in-visualforce-cant-read-selected-item-from-dynamic-drop-down-li/11993935#11993935)

Comment: I tried a standard selectlist and I still didn't have any luck. It's clearing the select list, the value that is selected stays until another one is selected. After every vendor change it should show "Select a model".

Comment: You can Not clear the selected value on the standard SF selectlist with any JavaScript (only with actionFunction). Thats why my solution with hidden field. The selected value stored not in the selectList variable, it is stored in a visualforce hidden Field, and you can clear it or set any value with JavaScript. That is a trick. Try it.

Comment: So I took another shot at it. Here's a screenshot of my code...It's not working so I'm not sure if I did it right?
http://i.imgur.com/zujaE.png